# android - repeat a switch statement

Tags: java, android

In my app I want to randomly pick an image and put it in the center of the screen. After that, animations can be performed, the image will be moved and reset to its origin position afterwards. Then I want to choose a new image of the switch case, but the image always stays the same. How can I fix it?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnGestureListener
{       

        private ImageView imageView;
        float x1,x2;
        float y1, y2;  
        public int sco = 0;
        TextView score;
        final Random rand = new Random();

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {        
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                       
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);                        
                        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
                        imageView.setImageResource(getMyRandomResId());
                        score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);                  
            }


            int imag = rand.nextInt(4);
                int getMyRandomResId() {


                    switch (imag) {
                    case 0:

                        return R.drawable.a;
                    case 1:

                        return R.drawable.b;
                    case 2:

                        return R.drawable.c;
                    default:

                        return R.drawable.d;
                }
            }


            private boolean animationRunning = false;

            public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent)
            {

                final ViewPropertyAnimator animator = imageView.animate();

                switch (touchevent.getAction())
                {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    {

                        x1 = touchevent.getX();
                        y1 = touchevent.getY();
                        break;
                    }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    {

                        x2 = touchevent.getX();
                        y2 = touchevent.getY();

                        if (!animationRunning) {
                    //left to right sweep event on screen
                        if (x1 < x2 && (x2-x1)>=(y1-y2) && (x2-x1)>=(y2-y1)) {

                            animationRunning = true;                        
                            animator.translationX(imageView.getWidth() * 2)                             
                                    .setDuration(180)                                    
                                    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                            if(getMyRandomResId() == R.drawable.ballgrue) {
                                                sco++;
                                            }
                                            imageView.setTranslationX(0);
                                            imageView.setImageResource(getMyRandomResId()); 
                                            animationRunning = false;

                                        }
                                    })
                                    .start();           
                        }
            }
           }
           }
        }
}
```

Comment: Can I put it in a method without loosing the `getMyRandomResId()` part?

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger.  This is probably the fastest way to find the root cause of the problem.

Comment: But if a method is missing what will the debugger say?

Comment: I was wrong, it is inside a method, but you neglected to use an explicit access modifier (making it package private by default), which confused me.

Comment: Just move `int imag = rand.nextInt(4);` inside the method `int getMyRandomResId()`

Comment: Okay. So do you know how I might repeat the part then?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. To get another random number you just need to put the statement inside the function, so, every time you call the function, a new random number is generated. Whenever you need another image, just call that function, put it into a loop or wherever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            int getMyRandomResId() {

     int imag = rand.nextInt(4);
                switch (imag) {
                case 0:

                    return R.drawable.a;
                case 1:

                    return R.drawable.b;
                case 2:

                    return R.drawable.c;
                default:

                    return R.drawable.d;
            }
        }
```

the reason you got a same image bcoz of this only

Hope it helps